# How to find the solutions for the equation $2^x = 4x$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, roots

How do I solve the equation $2^x = 4x$? So, the obvious answer by inspection is $x=4$, but I need an analytical solution to this, something rigorous pls.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw#Example_1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please be careful with the tags, Your question is not about `algebraic-number-theory`.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks. What Tag would have been appropriate pls?

Comment: Thanks. But is the Lambert W.  Function's method an analytical approach? I'm confused. I hear it's numerical.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699104/solving-4x-ex-without-graphing-and-looking-for-intersection

Comment: @user517110 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=2^x-4x$.

Thus, $$f''(x)=2^x\ln^22>0,$$ which says that $f$ is a convex function, which gives that our equation has two real roots maximum.

But $4$ and $0<x_1<1$ are roots.

The value of $x_1$ we can not get by elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^x=4x$$
$e^{x\ln(2)}=4x\quad\to\quad xe^{-x\ln(2)}=\frac14\quad\to\quad \left(-x\ln(2)\right)e^{\left(-x\ln(2)\right)}= -\frac{\ln(2)}{4}$

The general solution of this kind of equation cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. We need infinite series or a special function : The Lambert's W function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

$$-x\ln(2)=W\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{4} \right)$$
The result is :
$$x=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}W\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{4} \right)$$
The $W(X)$ function is a multi-valuated function. In the real range $-e^{-1}<X<0$ they are two real roots : 
$$\begin{cases}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{4} \right)=-4\ln(2) \quad\to\quad x=4\\W_0\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{4} \right)\simeq-0.214811 \quad\to\quad x \simeq 0.3099069  \end{cases}$$ 
The second root is not rational. An approximate is computed thanks to any mathematical software where the Lambert function is implemented. Or alternatively with recursive numerical calculus (Newton-Raphson method for example).

Answer (score 2):

A bit of  detail:

$ f''(x) \gt 0$, $f= 2^x-4x$ convex, does not , by itself, imply  that  $f(x) = 0$ has $2$ distinct zeroes.

1)$y= x^2 +1$, convex, has no zeroes ,

2) $y= x^2,$ $x_1=x_2 =0$, double zero.

But since $f(x) = 2^x -4x$ is convex, and:

positive at $x= 0,$

negative at $x=1$ ,

positive for $x \gt 4,$

we conclude that $f(x)$ has  two distinct roots:

$x_1 = 4$, by inspection, and $0 \lt x_2\lt 1$.

Comment: nice pointing out Peter !

Comment: Gimusi, you are really nice. I watch you racing ahead! Formidable!Keep it up as long you enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

For a rigorous proof you have to study the function $f(x)=2^x-4x$ showing analitically that it can't have more than two roots.

Comment: Bit how do I show one of the solutions s 4?

Comment: @user517110 you can show and prove analitically that you have only two roots and find also the range, the trivial root can be found by inspection (it is sufficient that it works), the other can be found by numerical methods

Comment: @user517110 in other words what you need is to prove that only 2 solution exist, the calculation of the roots is another kind of issue

Comment: Oh! Since the function is a continuous one on R. Will the Intermediate Value Theorem suffice that there's a root in the interval [0,1] for example? Since f(0)*f(1)<0

Comment: @user517110 tio prove the existence of ony two roots you have to show that f has a minimum <0 and that it can "touch" x axis more than 2 times by decreasing/increasing or convexity arguments.

Comment: ops...it can't touch I mean!