# Inverting a function: proof of $W(x) = \ln\frac{x}{\ln\frac{x}{\ddots}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, inverse-function, lambert-w

for $|W(x)|>1$, $W$ The Lambert W-function:
$$ W(x) =\ln\cfrac{x}{\ln\cfrac{x}{\ln\cfrac{x}{\ddots}}}  $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context : [This reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) contains your continued fraction expansions of Lambert's $W$ function. It is valid in the complex domain under the condition $|W(w)|>1$ ; one finds there another one, with $\exp$ instead of $\log$, valid for $|W(w)|<1$ (see below). See also the answer by Robert Israel [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693561).

In the following, I will restrict my attention to real values of variable $w$.

Let us first rewrite your formula under the following form for real positive values of $w$ :

> A) If $w>e : a_{n+1}=\ln(\frac{w}{\ a_{n}})$ with for example $a_0=2$ has a limit $L=W(w)$.

**knowing that you have to switch to another function in the other case** :

> B) If $w<e : b_{n+1}=\exp(\frac{w}{\ b_{n}})$ with for example $b_0=2$ has a limit $L$ s.t. $W(w)=\dfrac{w}{L}$.

Special case :

> If $w=e$,... $W(w)=1$.

(the resp. convergences of $a_n$ and $b_n$ are very slow when $w$ is close to $e$)

[image]

*Fig. 1 : This picture features two different things : 1) The principal branch of Lambert function $W$, which is defined as the inverse of function $y=xe^{x}$ on the region where the latter is increasing ; 2) an example of "cobweb convergence" (in case A)) to a limit $L=W(w)$ of iterative sequence $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ where $f(x)=\ln(w/x)=ln(x)-ln(w)$ (in the case $w=4$ and $u_0=2$).*

**Remarks :**

1. This cobweb convergence is convincing graphically ; but we must "guarantee" that it exists. This is due to the fact that $f'(L)=-1/L=-1/W(w) \approx -0.8$ with absolute value $<1$ warranting cobweb convergence, a classical consequence of Mean Value Theorem). But it remains, using MVT, to prove convergence in a rigorous way using a narrow enough interval around the limit.
2. Connection of the continued fraction (**under the restriction that the notations make sense...** as @fedja has remarked)  with Lambert function :
   $$W(x)=\ln\dfrac{x}{W(x)} \iff \exp(W(x)) = \dfrac{x}{W(x)}$$

(by taking $\exp$ on both sides), itself equivalent to the definition of (the principal branch of) Lambert $W$ function.
$$W(x)\exp(W(x))=x.$$

3. Good numerical methods about Lambert function can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1628.pdf).

Comment: it is more elegant indeed,but that proof  was just a way to contextualise the question about the convergence of $a_{n} $ dependent of $f$

Comment: This "short proof" only shows that if the RHS (in the original post) makes any sense at all, it must be the LHS. However it leaves the question of whether the RHS can be understood as the usual limit of finite "composition towers" wide open.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof by recursive definition:
$$
f(x)=\ln\cfrac{x}{\ln\cfrac{x}{\ln\cfrac{x}{\ddots}}}\\
f(x)=\ln\frac{x}{f(x)}\\
e^{f(x)}=\frac{x}{f(x)}\\
f(x)e^{f(x)}=x\\
f(x)=W(x)
$$